# modulenotfounderror no module named 'networkx' python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I am using python3 and I installed networkx and I import it in my code. When I run my python code file in command line (`python3 file.py`), I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networkx'
```

While when I run `python3` in command line and I import networkx, it will be imported well, without any error:
[image]

What the problem is?

Comment: Did you install the package with pip?

Comment: @Palinuro Yes, I did.

Comment: In the same environment?

Comment: @Palinuro Yes. I installed it by a yaml file as a new env and I activated env. Then I run my python file and I get this error while when I python3 and import networkx, I dont get any error. I run both under the same env.

Comment: why don't you perform the following steps to debug and check if the env is same that u wanted to use:
1. print the system path (sys.path)
2. print the list of pks installed (os.system(pip freeze))